# PHP Unit Testing without depending on the real server connection

Tags: php, unit-testing, zend-framework2

I have a class that has a connection to a running server (does not run on that server). I test that class and its methods with ZF2 PHP Unit Test. The test succeeded but when the server is down and the connection to that server failed, the test failed too. So I find out that my test depends on that server connection. I don't want to depend on the real server connection to succeed my test. I have searched on the Internet, but most of the websites provide only the basic PHP Unit Testing. Can someone help me testing my class using Zend Framework 2 PHP Unit Test, please? Thanks in advanced!

Comment: check this right here. Having the same situation

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30343887

Answer (score 1):

If you want to unit test your classes, the classes shouldn't make the http connections directly. Inject a connection adapter into you class, that you want to unit test. Then, in the unit test create a mock object as a substitution for the connection adapter and inject it into the unit tested class.

You can find a more detailed explanation here:

http://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/2015/07/refactoring-the-cat-api-client-part-2/