# PHPUnit RabbitMQ: write test for create connection function

Tags: php, phpunit, rabbitmq

I'm facing the following problem. I've wrote a function that create a connection object (AMQPConnection) given the required parameters. Now I want to write the corresponding unit test. I just don't know how to do it without having the RabbitMQ broker running. Here is the function in question:

```php
public function getConnection($hostKey, array $params)
{
    $connection = null;
    try {

        $connection = new AMQPConnection(
            $params['host'],
            $params['port'],
            $params['username'],
            $params['password'],
            $params['vhost']
        );

        // set this server as default for next connection connectionAttempt
        $this->setDefaultHostConfig($hostKey, $params);

        return $connection;
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {

        if ($this->isAttemptExceeded()) {
            return $connection;
        } else {
            // increment connection connectionAttempt
            $this->setConnectionAttempt($this->getConnectionAttempt() + 1);

            return $this->getConnection($hostKey, $params);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You usually don't test code like this as a Unittest since the result would more likely tell you that your server is installed correctly and not that your code is working.

Do you test if PDO returns a valid database connection?

It could make sense if you test your installation but not to test if the php c libs are working correctly.

Comment: Hi chozilla, Thanks for the quick reaction. This right is not related to `PDO` or `database`. Thing kind of things may be handle the same way, I just don't know. It's about RabbitMQ and connection to a broker.

Comment: @dickwan it's the same - you don't test connection to database, and you don't test connections to rabbitmq, just because it's not your code - it just works, trust it. Otherwise you would have to test the whole php standard library before you started using it.

Comment: @zerkms: Oh thank you for the clarifications. Now I wonder how I can assure that to code portion is covered.

Comment: @dickwan make a "Integration" or "installation" test-suite. But don't run it. Only when you install a server.

Comment: @chozilla: After your responses, I opted - in order to achieve good code coverage in my unit test - to use an anonymous function to return (inject) an AMQPConnection object. Thus isolating the code that create a connection to the server from the rest. I'll post later on what I changed in my code.

Answer (score 0):

You should add an ability to change the class being instantiated.

1. Add an ability to change the connector class via constructor or setter, with a default AMQPConnector class by default. Use it to create a connector object. [Example](https://github.com/vyuldashev/laravel-queue-rabbitmq/blob/c8f25520a5a8ecb8ff938ef3bad9bba783e7c7f6/src/Queue/Connectors/RabbitMQConnector.php#L47)
2. Create a mocked connector class for unit tests. [Example](https://github.com/vyuldashev/laravel-queue-rabbitmq/blob/c8f25520a5a8ecb8ff938ef3bad9bba783e7c7f6/tests/Mock/AmqpConnectionFactorySpy.php#L4)
3. Use it setting the mock class via constructor or setter in tests.  [Example](https://github.com/vyuldashev/laravel-queue-rabbitmq/blob/c8f25520a5a8ecb8ff938ef3bad9bba783e7c7f6/tests/Queue/Connectors/RabbitMQConnectorTest.php#L58)

You could also do assertions on what arguments are passed to the connector constructor.

Another way would be to use [amqp interop](https://github.com/queue-interop/queue-interop#amqp-interop) so you are not coupled to any implementation. Much easier to tests as you deal with pure interfaces only.

Answer (score -1):

@chozilla
@zerkms
So thanks to your hints, I've decided to use Closure in order to isolate the code portion connecting to the server.
Here is the closure:

```php
$connectionFunction = function ($params) {
            return new AMQPStreamConnection(
                $params['host'],
                $params['port'],
                $params['username'],
                $params['password'],
                $params['vhost']
            );
        };
```

And here the modified `getConnection()` function

```php
/**
 * @param string $hostKey The array key of the host connection parameter set
 * @param array $params The connection parameters set
 * @return null|AMQPStreamConnection
 */
public function getConnection($hostKey, array $params)
{
    $connection = null;
    try {
        $connection = call_user_func($connectionFunction, $params);

        // set this server as default for next connection connectionAttempt
        $this->setDefaultHostConfig($hostKey, $params);

        return $connection;
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {

        if ($this->isAttemptExceeded()) {
            return $connection;
        } else {
            // increment connection connectionAttempt
            $this->setConnectionAttempt($this->getConnectionAttempt() + 1);

            return $this->getConnection($hostKey, $params);
        }
    }
}
```

For the unit test I did the following:

```php
$mockConnection = $this->getMockBuilder('PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPStreamConnection')
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();

$connectionFunction = function ($params) use ($mockConnection) {
    return $mockConnection;
};
```

Or this to have an Exception.

```php
$connectionFunction = function ($params)  {
    throw new \Exception;
};
```

**N.B.**: I'm using `AMQPStreamConnection` in the **getConnection()** function since `AMQPConnection` is marked as deprecated in `PhpAmqpLib`